# Perl REGEX, having problems with matching non alphanumerics in a string, on the fly

Tags: regex, perl, logcat

Apologies for what will probably be an obvious answer!  I am trying to run a Perl search on an adb Logcat stream (on the fly) to exit when a particular string is found.  The string I am looking for (which is part of a larger line of text) is this...

```
RIL(1) :[0129]< OPERATOR {O2 -UK, 23410, 23410}
```

I made a few attempts at regex, but still my script just doesn't detect it, here's my latest attempt below

```
m/RIL\(1\)\s\:\[[\d+]\]\<\sOPERATOR\s\{[\w+]\,\s[\d+]\,\s[\d+]\}/
```

The full adb logcat line of text is this...

```
D/RILJ    (  663):  RIL(1) :[0129]< OPERATOR {O2 -UK, 23410, 23410}
```

My script is ok as it works with other strings, it's just my regex is a bit broken as I am new to it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
MikG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

1. You're doing `[\d+]` when you mean `\d+`. `\d+` is equivalent to `[0-9]+` ("any digit, at least once").  When you say `[\d+]`, that's actually equivalent to `[+d]` ("either '+' or 'd'")
2. You're escaping your commas. That doesn't actually hurt anything but it's ugly and unnecessary. Commas aren't special in most contexts of regular expressions.
3. You're trying to match `O2 -UK` with `\w+`. `\w` is the "word" character class. Roughly, it matches characters that are commonly legal in identifiers in programming languages: `[a-zA-Z_]`

To fix #3, you have a few choices. If it's always `O2 -UK`, just match against that literal text. You could also match against `[^,]+,` ("anything that's not a comma, at least once, followed by a comma"). I'd have to know the range of that value to come up with a good in-between pattern.

Comment: Thank you Nathaniel, my earlier errors now seem obvious, hopefully I will get better with practice.  Indeed it looks like the main stumbling point was the 'O2 -UK' part of the string, so using your suggestion of '[^,]+,' fixed the problem (aside from my other beginners errors!).  Thanks again!

Comment: Don't get discouraged! Regular expressions are a wonderful tool, but the learning curve is steep. A good start to debugging is to chop your non-working regex into smaller pieces. (I ran yours with everything up through "OPERATOR" and it worked, so then I knew to look more closely at the second half.)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use this kind of things: `[\d+]`. Instead, use this: `\d+` or `[0-9]+`.

You don't have to escape `<` or `,`

So, try something like this:

```
m/RIL\(1\)\s:\[\d+\]<\sOPERATOR\s\{\w+,\s\d+,\s\d+\}/
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
m/RIL\(1\)\s:\[\d+]<\sOPERATOR\s\{\w+,\s\d+,\s\d+}/
```

if you put a quantifier inside square brackets, the quantifier is seen as literal.

You only need to escape: `( ) [ { ^ $ . * + ? | \`

Answer (score 0):

I think a regex is your problem, Here I found a answer which contains the regex..

Use this regex to match alphanumeric content: Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\W|_");

Source:[Regex Expressions for all non alphanumeric symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114027/regex-expressions-for-all-non-alphanumeric-symbols)