# Can not remove hided symbol

Tags: c#, undefined-symbol

I am write a program, that analyze the text from MS Word .doc/.docx file, so I need to split text to words.

I am use String.Split method for this with most popular characters as separators.
All is good, but MS Word use some hided symbols and I can't find one symbol.

When I click to "Show hided symbols" in Word, it looks like this [hided symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8MFa.png).

I need to know about it at least: hex code in Unicode, name, etc.

Here are all my separators

```
      char[] separators = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '"', '\'', ';', '-', '‴', '‵',' ', '\b','\x00A0',
            ')', '\\', '*', '%', '$', '@', '{', '}', '„', '“','…', '′', '″','’','   ', '\x2007', '\x200C',
            '№', '(', '?', '!', '_', '\t', '\n', '\r', '\a', '<', '>','‶', '‷','    ','\0', '\x202F',
            '/', '~', '#', '+', '—', ']', '[', '|', '«', '»', '&', '–', '¶', '‘', '\f', '\x2060'};

      string[] splittedWords = text.Split(separator);
```

Comment: A regex split with `\b` (word boundary) may be a better way to do this.

Comment: `doc` is a binary format and `docx` a zipped package of XML files, hence also a binary. There are no words to split. What `hided` symbol are you talking about and where did you find it? How did you read the text?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114027/regex-expressions-for-all-non-alphanumeric-symbols to replace with a regular expression

Comment: Besides, Word Interop provides a collection of word, through the [Words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.words(v=office.14).aspx) interface. You don't need to split the text yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this is to use a regular expression. With regex you can match, replace and split words without the need to declare your separators. Try looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx 
Hope this helps